# Creating an onChange select drop down with javascript and php but it's not working

Tags: php, javascript, sql, onchange

What I am trying to do is create a drop down  container of 32 different locations in Scotland and when one of the selections is selected, for example, Glasgow it should go to a URL which displays content such as heading, text, for each article in a div WHERE location = Glasgow.

I have no error messages or any sort of recognition that my code has worked as when I select one of the four on the drop down it does absolutely nothing.

Can come clean up and put right what I've done so far? I would be extremely greatful!

Here is my files which are being used:

header.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#location').change(function(){
            //Retrieve Content from the back-end PHP page, and pass the ID selected
            var url = 'location.php?location=' + $(this).val();
            $('#txtHint').load(url);
        });
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
     <div id="header">
        <div class="headerLeftContent">
            <select id='location'>
                    <option href="Link to a dynamic page with all the content from glasgow" value="Glasgow">Glasgow</option>
                    <option href="Link to a dynamic page with all the content from x" value="x">x</option>
                    <option href="Link to a dynamic page with all the content from test" value="test">test</option>
                    <option href="Link to a dynamic page with all the content from edinburgh" value="Edinburgh">Edinburgh</option>
            </select>
            <div id='txtHint'></div>
        </div>          
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

location.php

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect('xxxxxx', 'xxxxxx', 'xxxxxx');
$select_db = mysql_select_db('xxxxxx');

$location = $_REQUEST['location'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM podContent WHERE location = '.$location.'";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
echo $row['text'];
}

mysql_close($connect);

?>
```

And please any comments regarding 'SQL injection' or how 'mysql' should be 'PDO' are unwanted as I do understand this but I am simply testing at the moment and will amend this.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do your `<option>` elements have an `href` attribute?

Comment: It's simply to help people understand what I'm trying to do, I want that to link to a URL where the content has a location = Glasgow or Edinburgh etc.

Comment: Ahh okay. Look at the Javascript here: http://jsfiddle.net/r5SWJ/ and try to use that form of `load`. Note how it uses the second parameter of `load` (the callback) to show the AJAX's result

Comment: @Ian so I pasted that into my code and where it said success on the jsfiddle platform when I uploaded this code to my server I was hit with an alert saying error.

Comment: So that means you have a communication/server problem. Now instead, try this to get more info: `$('#txtHint').load(url, function (response, status, xhr) { alert("Load result: " + status + " ||| " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText); });`

Comment: Okay. So I uploaded that and I came up with an error message saying "Load Result: error ||| 404 Not Found"! I may stress that I do not have a URL for each location. And also can you explain what 'var url = "/echo/json/";' means? as I do not have this file path if thats what its referring to.

Comment: So that means your "location.php" can't be found. Is "location.php" in the same directory as "header.php"?

Comment: It certainly is in the same directory, yes.

Comment: Sorry, the `var url = "/echo/json/";` was used for testing in the jsFiddle. I had said to only copy/use the code for `load` method, so like use all of your code, but replace **your** `.load` line with `$('#txtHint').load(url, function (response, status, xhr) { alert("Load result: " + status + " ||| " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText); });`

Comment: Oh right. I changed that but now it comes up with absolutely nothing just the same symptoms as when I first had the problem. Can you see anything else that could be the problem?

Comment: No sorry I am getting Load Result: Success ||| 200 OK. I didn't add an extra '});' at the end for the $(document).ready! Now what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a mistake concatenating your location name inside your MySQL query, and it's not matching anything (so nothing is `echo`ed back). Change this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM podContent WHERE location = '.$location.'";
```

to

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM podContent WHERE location = '$location'";
```

(Unless you have stuff like `.Glasgow.` in your database...)

Then you have to call `mysql_query($query)` as Alon suggested.

Comment: Hellow having same problem like @AyeTry but it doesnot helped me :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to use mysql_query and pass the resource to the mysql_fetch_array function:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM podContent WHERE location = '.$location.'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
    echo $row['text'];
 }
```

Comment: yeah that's fine I realised that straight after I posted this.