# Cannot get my javascript/php onchange function to work

Tags: php, javascript, onchange

I have already made a post regarding this issue no longer than 2hours ago but I really need to get this finished ASAP.

What I am trying to do is create a drop down  container of 32 different locations in Scotland and when one of the selections is selected, for example, Glasgow it should go to a URL which displays content such as heading, text, for each article in a div WHERE location = Glasgow.

Currently I do not have URL's for each location.

I the following message when I select a new option: "Load Result: success ||| 200 OK"

Can someone be so kind to provide me with the last piece to this frustrating puzzle?

Here is my files which are being used:

header.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#location').change(function(){
    //Retrieve Content from the back-end PHP page, and pass the ID selected
    var url = 'location.php?location=' + $(this).val();
    $('#txtHint').load(url, function (response, status, xhr) { alert("Load result: " + status + " ||| " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText); 
    });
  });
});    
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div class="headerLeftContent">
            <select id="location">
                    <option value="Glasgow">Glasgow</option>
                    <option value="x">x</option>
                    <option value="test">test</option>
                    <option value="Edinburgh">Edinburgh</option>
            </select>
            <div id='txtHint'></div>
        </div>          
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

location.php

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx');
$select_db = mysql_select_db('xxx');

$location = $_REQUEST['location'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM podContent WHERE location = '.$location.'";

$result = mysql_query( $query, $connect );

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row['text'];
}

?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried loading this in Mozilla with Firebug JavaScript debugger? It shows all JS errors. When you call location.php directly-- does it shows correct results?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating an onChange select drop down with javascript and php but it's not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903822/creating-an-onchange-select-drop-down-with-javascript-and-php-but-its-not-worki)

Comment: I moved my answer to the original question, and am voting to close this one as a duplicate okay?

Answer (score 0):

Correct this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM podContent WHERE location = ".$location;
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. `$query = "SELECT * FROM podContent WHERE location = '.$location.'";` has two additional dots. It should be `$query = "SELECT * FROM podContent WHERE location = '$location'";`.
2. Before using the value `$location` from the user, you should escape it with [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). Note this function is deprecated, and will be removed on future versions of PHP. You should take a look into [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/book.pdo.php) and prepared statements.